# Moq, mockin an abstract class : the mocked object does cannot use methods implemented in the abstract class

Tags: c#, testing, moq

hi I have a code similar to the following:

```
        public abstract class MyAbstractClass
        {
            public virtual string DoSomething(string s1, string s2)
            {
                return this.DoSomethingElse(s1 + s2);
            }

            protected abstract string DoSomethingElse(string s);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            var myMock = new Mock<MyAbstractClass>();
            myMock.Protected().Setup<string>("DoSomethingElse", ItExpr.IsAny<string>()).Returns<string>(x => $"{x} I did it.");

            var result = myMock.Object.DoSomething("a", "b");

        }
```

I would expect the result in the test to be "ab I did it", but I get back a null. I noticed that if remove the "virtual" to the "DoSomething" method, than it would return as expected. The problem is that I need this method to be virtual. And honestly in my understanding of how moq work it should return the "ab I did it", but maybe I am missing something.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you're calling the `DoSomething` method *using the mock object*, but because you haven't told the mock object to use the real implementation or `Setup` it, it's just going to "do nothing" (ie return null) by default.

The quick way to solve this is by setting the `CallBase = true` property for the mock object. Then, any method that isn't `Setup` will use the real implementation.

```
var myMock = new Mock<MyAbstractClass>() { CallBase = true };
myMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<string>("DoSomethingElse", ItExpr.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns("DoSomethingElseResult");

Console.WriteLine("DoSomething: " + myMock.Object.DoSomething("a", "b"));
```

This will print "DoSomething: DoSomethingElseResult", which should be exactly what you want. The mock object runs `DoSomething` using the real implementation, and the real implementation of `DoSomething` runs the mocked implementation of `DoSomethingElse`.

Comment: Great answer! :)

Comment: I don't, however, have an explanation for "why does taking the `virtual` keyword off when using the original code make it work correctly?" https://dotnetfiddle.net/buE1YH